# My code is printing an extra "None" after every call of the method getTotalByKind.. Where could it be from?

Tags: python

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, price, kind):
        self.name = name 
        self.price = price
        self.kind = kind


    def getPrice(self):
        return self.price

    def getName(self):
        return self.name 

    def getKind(self):
        return self.kind

class Cart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        pass

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.list.append(item)

    def getTotalsByKind(self, kind):
        total = 0
        for i in self.list:
            if i.getKind() == kind:
                total += i.getPrice()
        t = '{:.2f}'.format(total)
        print "The total for %s items is %s" %(kind, t)
```

Comment: Are you calling `print cart.getTotalsByKind()` perhaps?

Comment: Show your *complete* code.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the *return value* of the method.

Remove the `print` statement from before the `.getTotalsByKind()` method call; the method itself does all the printing.

Your method does not have an explicit `return` statement, which means the default return value `None` is used:

```
>>> def foo():
...     # Nothing is returned in this function
...     print 'Bar!'
... 
>>> print foo()
Bar!
None
>>> foo()
Bar!
```

The better alternative is to have your method return the string to be printed:

```
def getTotalsByKind(self, kind):
    total = 0
    for i in self.list:
        if i.getKind() == kind:
            total += i.getPrice()
    t = '{:.2f}'.format(total)
    return "The total for %s items is %s" %(kind, t)
```

Now you can do different things with the returned string, not just print it.

Comment: Thanks, you are right the print just needed to be a return.

Answer (score 2):

You should make `getTotalsByKind` *return* the string, not print it.  To do this, make this line:

```
print "The total for %s items is %s" %(kind, t)
```

like this:

```
return "The total for %s items is %s" %(kind, t)
```

Now, when you print the results of `getTotalsByKind`, it will work.

Functions, by default, return `None` if they come to the end of themselves without returning.  And, by using `print` with `getTotalsByKind` (which you must be doing), you are telling Python to print the return value of `getTotalsByKind`, which is `None`.

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe I didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

You don't show this part of your code, but my guess is that you're doing `print cart.getTotalsByKind(...)`, thereby telling Python to print the return value of that function. But it doesn't return anything, therefore it returns `None`. Instead that method *prints* the total.

You have fallen prey to a poorly named method: `getTotalsByKind` implies that the totals will be *returned,* but there's only one total, and it is printed instead of being returned. I would name this method `printTotalByKind` instead. Or name it `getTotalByKind` and have the caller do the printing (and formatting). Then your method could be written much more simply as follows:

```
def getTotalByKind(self, kind):
    return sum(item.price for item in self.list if item.kind == kind)
```

This isn't related to your question, but your getter methods are entirely superfluous and should probably be removed. You can already get an item's price via `item.price`, no need for the overhead of calling a function to do the same thing. [PINJ](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).